# Cannot get Header in my emailed file from EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, header

This sql yields the correct format I'm looking for in my excel file, but it won't add a header to my excel file once emailed. I played with some settings, then it throws the error -2147467259. I've tried playing with @query_result_header  = 1 and @query_result_header  = 0. I'm stumped on this one.

```
set @SQL2 = 
'


SELECT [Rx_Date]
      ,[Fill_Date]
      ,convert(varchar(10), [Days_Supply]) 
      ,convert(varchar(10), [Quantity_Dispensed]) 
      ,convert(varchar(11),[NDC]) 
      ,[Drug_Name]
      ,[Pay_Type]
      ,[Prescriber_DEA_Nbr]
      ,convert(varchar(10),[Prescriber_NPI_Nbr]) 
      ,[Prescriber_Last_Name]
      ,[Prescriber_First_Name]
      ,[Prescriber_Middle_Name]
      ,[Prescriber_Address_1]
      ,[Prescriber_Address_2]
      ,[Prescriber_City]
      ,[Prescriber_State]
      ,convert(varchar(5),[Prescriber_Zip]) 
      ,convert(varchar(15),[Patient_ID]) 
      ,convert(varchar(5),[Patient_Zip]) 
  FROM [Integrity].[dbo].[ab_consumption_review_results]'




DECLARE @sbj as varchar(200) = 'AB Consumption Review '+ CAST(CAST(GETDATE() as date) as varchar(12))
DECLARE @fileName AS VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @body as varchar (200)


SET @fileName =  @str + '_' + (SELECT [PHRM_DEA_NBR] FROM [Reference].[dbo].[Stores] where [STORE_NBR] = @str
   and STORE_OPEN_STATUS_IND = 'y')  + '.xls'

SET @body ='Hello, 
<br/> Attached is the three month AB Consumption Review '+ @start  + ' to '+ @end +'.'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Integrity',
@subject = @sbj,
@body = @body,
@body_format ='HTML',
@recipients = 'jason@hot.com',
@query = @SQL2,
@execute_query_database = 'Integrity',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_header  = 1,
@query_no_truncate = 1,
@query_result_no_padding = 0,
@query_result_separator =  '    ',
@query_attachment_filename = @fileName
```

I've also tried this for my @SQL2, but no luck

```
set @SQL2 = 
'
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT ''Rx_Date'' as Rx_Date
      ,''Fill_Date'' as Fill_Date
      ,''Days_Supply'' as Days_Supply
      ,''Quantity_Dispensed'' as Quantity_Dispensed
      ,''NDC'' as NDC
      ,''Drug_Name'' as Drug_Name
      ,''Pay_Type'' as Pay_Type
      ,''Prescriber_DEA_Nbr'' as Prescriber_DEA_Nbr
      ,''Prescriber_NPI_Nbr'' as Prescriber_NPI_Nbr
      ,''Prescriber_Last_Name'' as Prescriber_Last_Name
      ,''Prescriber_First_Name'' as Prescriber_First_Name
      ,''Prescriber_Middle_Name'' as Prescriber_Middle_Name
      ,''Prescriber_Address_1'' as Prescriber_Address_1
      ,''Prescriber_Address_2'' as Prescriber_Address_2
      ,''Prescriber_City'' as Prescriber_City
      ,''Prescriber_State'' as Prescriber_State
      ,''Prescriber_Zip'' as Prescriber_Zip
      ,''Patient_ID'' as Patient_ID
      ,''Patient_Zip'' as Patient_Zip

      UNION ALL




SELECT [Rx_Date]
      ,[Fill_Date]
      ,convert(varchar(10), [Days_Supply]) 
      ,convert(varchar(10), [Quantity_Dispensed]) 
      ,convert(varchar(11),[NDC]) 
      ,[Drug_Name]
      ,[Pay_Type]
      ,[Prescriber_DEA_Nbr]
      ,convert(varchar(10),[Prescriber_NPI_Nbr]) 
      ,[Prescriber_Last_Name]
      ,[Prescriber_First_Name]
      ,[Prescriber_Middle_Name]
      ,[Prescriber_Address_1]
      ,[Prescriber_Address_2]
      ,[Prescriber_City]
      ,[Prescriber_State]
      ,convert(varchar(5),[Prescriber_Zip]) 
      ,convert(varchar(15),[Patient_ID]) 
      ,convert(varchar(5),[Patient_Zip]) 
  FROM [Integrity].[dbo].[ab_consumption_review_results]'
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. The workaround that I did was to add the headers to a select query and union it with the real select query:

```
  SELECT '0' as 'Row Count'

      ,'[Rx_Date]'
      ,'[Fill_Date]'
      ,'[Days_Supply]' 
      ,'[Quantity_Dispensed]' 
      ,'[NDC]' 
      ,'[Drug_Name]'
      ,'[Pay_Type]'
      ,'[Prescriber_DEA_Nbr]'
      ,'[Prescriber_NPI_Nbr]' 
      ,'[Prescriber_Last_Name]'
      ,'[Prescriber_First_Name]'
      ,'[Prescriber_Middle_Name]'
      ,'[Prescriber_Address_1]'
      ,'[Prescriber_Address_2]'
      ,'[Prescriber_City]'
      ,'[Prescriber_State]'
      ,'[Prescriber_Zip]' 
      ,'[Patient_ID]' 
      ,'[Patient_Zip]' 
UNION
SELECT 
      '1' as 'RowCount'
      ,[Rx_Date]
      ,[Fill_Date]
      ,convert(varchar(10), [Days_Supply]) 
      ,convert(varchar(10), [Quantity_Dispensed]) 
      ,convert(varchar(11),[NDC]) 
      ,[Drug_Name]
      ,[Pay_Type]
      ,[Prescriber_DEA_Nbr]
      ,convert(varchar(10),[Prescriber_NPI_Nbr]) 
      ,[Prescriber_Last_Name]
      ,[Prescriber_First_Name]
      ,[Prescriber_Middle_Name]
      ,[Prescriber_Address_1]
      ,[Prescriber_Address_2]
      ,[Prescriber_City]
      ,[Prescriber_State]
      ,convert(varchar(5),[Prescriber_Zip]) 
      ,convert(varchar(15),[Patient_ID]) 
      ,convert(varchar(5),[Patient_Zip]) 
  FROM [Integrity].[dbo].[ab_consumption_review_results]
  'ORDER BY 'Row Count'
```

also added the 'Row Count' to the select queries to keep the heading on top of the query result.

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: Just helped me on a very similar issue.  Nice work!